# How to configure Sublime Text's Anaconda package's autocomplete so that it give 'print()' instead of 'print'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, autocomplete, sublimetext3, sublime-anaconda

I've tried many times playing around with both the user and default settings but to no avail. The anaconda package is great and they say that it is really configurable but I don't know how and can't seem to find anyone who can address my problem.

Comment: This question would be better asked on [su]

Comment: What’s super user

Comment: "Super User is for computer enthusiasts and power users. If you have a question about [...] computer software [...] then you’re in the right place to ask your question!" -- [su] Help center

Comment: Thanks man I’ll check it out for sure

Comment: (Mods: Migrate to SU?)